# Put up a picture

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I was wondering about when to use this phrasal verb ‘put up’

As far as I know, if someone says they’re putting up a picture, It means they’re displaying it on their wall, but could it mean they post a picture online? Could the meaning of it be changed by context?

Comment: Yeah - the *specific* meaning depends on context. Or to put it another way, you *can* validly ***put*** something online, as well as ***post*** it online. And in very many contexts it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to follow ***put*** with a preposition such as ***up*** or ***out***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh, I got it now! Thank you v much!

Answer (score 1):

Context is very important in English, so it yes, the normal meaning of 'putting up a picture' would be 'on a wall' but for a web developer, it would be perfectly valid to use exactly the same phrase for adding to a website.

A very similar example with a rather different meaning would be 'putting up with a picture' which would generally mean that a picture was already on display.

Comment: Thank you v much for your explanation.